# How to make a conditional IF THEN on this statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, conditional-statements

This MySQL will increment a user's reputation by 5 when an upvote is submitted.

```
UPDATE  user_profiles
SET     reputation = reputation +5
WHERE   user_id = $question_author_id;
```

Now I want to make a distinction:

- if the upvote is for a question, the increment should be 5,
- if the upvote is for an answer, the increment should be 10.

An answer can be identified by the presence of an integer in the field **forum_qa_parent_id** of table **forum_qa**.

So I came up with this but it doesn't work:

```
UPDATE       user_profiles
IF (SELECT   forum_qa_parent_id 
    FROM     forum_qa 
    WHERE    forum_qa_id = $question_id) IS NOT NULL 
    THEN SET reputation = reputation +10 
    WHERE    user_id = $question_author_id;
ELSE SET     reputation = reputation +5 
WHERE        user_id = $question_author_id;
END IF;
```

Anyone care to show me how to make this work?

Comment: :) - syntax error - sorry for the vagueness... - but @derek offered a great solution

Comment: _What_ syntax error? </trying-to-train-you-to-write-better-questions>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a CASE statement if you're doing logical comparisons within a query. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

```
UPDATE  user_profiles
SET     reputation = reputation + 
    case when (
        SELECT   forum_qa_parent_id 
        FROM     forum_qa 
        WHERE    forum_qa_id = $question_id) is not null then 10 else 5 end
WHERE   user_id = $question_author_id;
```

Something along those lines - you might need to touch that one up a bit.

Comment: hi @ derek - thanks for the tip - works nicely after I made a minor mod -- i removed `exists` and put `is not null` right before `then 10...` -- i think `exists` doesn't work because it checks for a row and not `NULL` -- not sure if it's the case, but maybe you can update the answer?

Comment: `EXISTS (SELECT ...)` is very commonly used. @torr: Have you tried it?

Comment: But you are right, EXISTS checks for row(s). And you want to check if the field has a `NULL` or not.

Comment: @ypercube: In this case, the row always exists. It's the value of the row the OP wants to `CASE` on.